Renew Access Token from Refresh Token using Azure.Identity
I have a ASP.NET Core application where I authenticate the user using .AddOpenIdConnect. I'm getting an Access Token which I can use to call the Microsoft Graph, which after some work I can use to call the Microsoft Graph.
The access token expires and that's why a refresh token is also provided. I can get new access + refresh tokens by calling the /token endpoint myself. However I'd rather leverage a MSFT library to actually call that endpoint and handle (de)serialisation of requests.
What MSFT library can I use to periodically renew the acces + refresh tokens? I've searched plentiful, but libraries have come and gone over the years and it is difficult to find current information. I need to have access to the refresh tokens, so I can store them for later use. So anything using a TokenCache (looking at MSAL.NET) is unusable to me.

AFAIK, you have to make use of token cache to renew the access token or by calling \token endpoint.
